# Flask render_template context not showing in URL

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass params to the URL in flask, but I can not get them to show up for anything.

```
@logout.route('/logout')
def logout_page():
    current_provider = current_oauth_user.get_provider()
    return render_template('index.html', provider=current_provider)
```

I expect to see `/logout?provider=facebook` but I just get `/logout`

Right now I am doing this:

```
@logout.route('/logout')
def logout_page():
    provider = request.args.get('provider')
    current_provider = current_oauth_user.get_provider()
    if not provider and current_provider:
        return redirect(url_for('logout.logout_page',
                                provider=current_provider))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

but that just seems so terrible.

Comment: You have some misunderstandings. Your backend cannot control route, but browser can. What you see `/logout` is that browser accesses. You cannot directly change it to `/logout?provider=facebook`. Even `redirect` is just asking browser to redirect, browser itself has the control to choose redirect or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should return some value using '/logout' path. 
So at first, you use `render_template(index.html)` under `def main()`. Then you create `def logout_page()` and return some value ( in your case is `current_provider`).

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout_page():
    current_provider = current_oauth_user.get_provider()
    return current_provider

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(port=8000)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still a bit confused. Could you give me an example?